# password.match expression isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My password.match is true when I type in an uncapitalised and a capitalised letter.
This is my code:

```
  if (password.match(/([()\[\]{}?!$%&\/=*+~,.;:<>-_])/)) {
    $("#passwordspecial").text("");
    check2 = 0;
}
```

My code to check the if it's capitalised is in this section:

```
 if (password.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/)) {
    $("#passwordbig").text("");
    check1 = 0;
}
```

So if I type in `gH` for example, the first section is true, but it should be false.

Comment: What exactly do you need to match?

Comment: Your first regex explained: https://regex101.com/r/kJ2xB4/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `>-_` inside of `[]`, which makes it a range from `>` (ASCII value 62) to `_` (ASCII value 95), which happens to include all uppercase letters.

Prefix that `-` with a backslash, like so:

```
if (password.match(/([()\[\]{}?!$%&\/=*+~,.;:<>\-_])/)) {
    $("#passwordspecial").text("");
    check2 = 0;
}
```

and `"gH"` will no longer match it.